# Volume of solid $y = x−4x^2$ revolved about y-axis using shell approach.

Tags: calculus, volume

I am attempting to solve the following problem and would like some validation in my approach/need some help on finding zeros if this is indeed the correct approach.

**Problem:**

> Find vol of solid of revolution - The region bounded by $y = x−4x^2$ and the $x$-axis revolved about the $y$-axis.

My approach:

1. Shells
2. $V= 2\pi$ * [integral of $\int_a^b x(x-4x^2)dx$
3. evaluate from b to a, and I'm assuming answer would be in pi cubic units because we're solving for volume.

How would I determine the bounds, and is my approach the correct one?
(apologies for the poor formatting, I am new to the site)

Thanks,
J

Comment: Typically to find bounds, I am given two equations, which i can set to zero and solve for, which is why this problem is throwing me off.

Comment: What is the appropriate range of values for $x$ (where does the parabola intersect the $x$-axis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all bounds $x-4x^2=0$ has roots $x=0, 0.25$. So these are your bounds. You have the integral setup correctly. So just evaluate the following. 
$$\int_0^{0.25}2\pi x(x-4x^2)dx$$

Why the bounds are so?

Because you have $f(x)=x(1-4x)$ as the top curve and $y=0$ i.e the x-axis as the bottom curve. You need to find the intersection of these curves to get the bounds.[1](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vxkoi0bces)

Comment: Thanks for this. What I gather now is that when solving for one equation and you have determined the method (shell method vs discs), set the equation to 0, to determine..well your zeros! You're a life saver!